# Cannot get HAX working for Android Emulator & the emulator appears to freeze

Tags: android, macos, cordova, android-emulator, osx-yosemite

I am running OS-X 10.10.2 Yosemite on my MacBook Air and have installed the latest version of the Android Studio (1.2) and it has a default SDK already pre-configured.

I am trying to setup the Intel HAXM to speed up the emulation - I have also setup the Ionic & Cordova frameworks (as i'll be using this to develop mobile apps).

I am using the command to start the emulator:

```
sudo cordova emulate android
```

This begins the process and opens up an Android Virtual Device and the 'android' word appears on the screen.

In the Terminal I get the following:

```
Waiting for emulator....
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit

HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
Booting up emulator (this may take a while)...............................
```

This appears to 'stick' on this screen - I have installed the Intel HAXM (1.2 is installed) but it doesn't seem to have been correctly configured - can anyone suggest how to fix. I have changed the RAM used by HAXM to 1GB and 768MB with no joy..

Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Comment: you should investigate if your CPU support VT-x and Intel Virtualization istruction

Comment: Have u checked the "Use Host Gpu" option and selected a x86 android version ??

Comment: I think its running now - seems quicker now I have turned on the Host GPU option thanks - please post that as an answer & i will accept